# Dex with Str build for Elden ring?

Tags: elden-ring

I am thinking to start Elden ring with a Vagabond focusing on strength, dexterity, endurance, and vigor. I mainly want to use shields but also bows. Does this make sense for a player new to the game? Should I keep dexterity and strength at an equal level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, it depends on the weapons you favor using. Weapons have scaling factors and minimum requirements and you generally want to level whatever factors are best for your weapons. Leveling strength and dexterity relatively evenly is fairly common and is known as a "quality" build. It should be fine for the early to mid game stages of Elden Ring. By the mid-game, you should have access to the re-spec mechanic in case you feel you need to change your build.